# IBM Global services method, gs method

Tags: architecture

Can anyone point me in the direction of information regarding this solution architecture method, ie the IBM global services method?

Comment: I'm talking about their solution architecture method, ie like 4+1 views but their own version. It's a way of documenting solution/system architectures. It's not a code artifact or API.

Answer (score 1):

GS Method is superseded by Unified Method Framework.

There's an article on the Krutchen 4+1 view here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/08/0108_cooks-cripps-spaas/

Also whilst not a direct UMF reference, Peter Cripps from the article above blogs regularly - a number of the early posts on his site cover aspects of this solution architecture including Component Modelling, System Context etc - http://softwarearchitecturezen.blogspot.com/